# When I use qsort for submitting my code in cses problems set it is not accepting it. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Tags: c, qsort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ll long long

#include <stdlib.h>

ll int comp(const void* a, const void *b)
{
    return *(long long *)b - *(long long *)a;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    ll int n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);

    ll int a[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",(a+i));
    }
     
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(ll int), comp);

    ll int cnt=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[i+1])
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    printf("%lld\n", cnt);
    cnt=0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to at least put the code in code blocks, but it's still pretty much unreadable. Please edit your code to properly indent and format it. (Also, you've tagged [c] and your code looks like C but you've mentioned C++11 in the title? Please clarify)

Comment: `qsort()` takes an `int` comparator function, not the unspeakable `ll int`. The function type has no relation to the the data that is being sorted.

Comment: SURYA 045, Note: `*(long long *)b - *(long long *)a` overflows for many values.

Comment: @SURYA 045 What is the program doing?

Comment: Aside: if you use `long long` instead of the lazy `ll int` that's only 3 more characters to type and is clear.

Comment: input/code.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
input/code.cpp:23:40: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)(const void*, const void*)' to '__compar_fn_t {aka int (*)(const void*, const void*)}' [-fpermissive]
           qsort(a,n,sizeof(ll int),comp);
                                        ^

Comment: @Yun it is C question

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 its c

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this is for sorting array

Comment: I have already pointed out the `long long int` is not the `int` function expected by `qsort` and mentioned in the error.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have used #define ll long long

Comment: `long long int` is the **wrong type** for the comparator function, macro or no.

Comment: @SURYA045 Apart from sorting it counts something.  What is it trying to count?

Comment: @WeatherVane got it , I think I should use *(ll int *)b-*(ll int *)a

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is counting the no of distinct elements

Comment: Get rid of `#define ll long long`

Comment: Nope, the comparator function must be `int comp(const void* a, const void *b)` and return an `int` value as documented. That `int` value is unrelated to the *type* of data that is being sorted.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok is there any way such that it works for long long int array??

Comment: `return (*(long long*)a > *(long long*)b) - (*(long long*)a < *(long long*)b);`